# While loop condition - matlab

Tags: matlab, while-loop

How can I make a while loop condition that is true when `x` is NOT 1 or 2, and only those two numbers?
I'd imagine it going something like this

```
while x ~= (1 || 2)
%blablabla
end
```

But that doesn't work in practice. How can I correctly write this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put `while x~=1 && x~=2`.

`(1 || 2)` will always be true and therefore the while loop is never entered. Logical expressions with double values in MATLAB classify as `true` everything that is non-zero (like 1 and 2) and everything that is zero as `false`